# error compiling Matconvnet R2019a, error using mex

Tags: c++, matlab, mex, matconvnet

i am traying to use Matconvnet library in: Matlab R2019a, windows 10.
i have already configure `MinGW 64mex -setup C++` i am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community Edition.

i had a problem releated with a `cl.exe` when running the `vl_compile` , but i fixed it adding this path to my variables enviorenment.

after that,  the vl_compilenn function can work for a moment but always stuck in part with this error saying something about the using of `mex`(i show you the error below):

i have seen a lot of problems releated with this one, but from 2016, anything wiht current information, i would really appreciate your help i am really stuck in this problem.

```
Error using mex
In file included from
C:\Users\Santiago\Documents\matconvnet-1.0-beta25\matlab\src\bits\impl\imread_helpers.hpp:19:0,
                 from
C:\Users\Santiago\Documents\matconvnet-1.0-beta25\matlab\src\bits\impl\imread_gdiplus.cpp:14:
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m128i _mm_hadd_epi16(__m128i,
__m128i)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:42:70:
error: '__builtin_ia32_phaddw128' was not
declared in this scope
   return (__m128i) __builtin_ia32_phaddw128
   ((__v8hi)__X, (__v8hi)__Y);
                                                                      ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m128i _mm_hadd_epi32(__m128i,
__m128i)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:48:70:
error: '__builtin_ia32_phaddd128' was not
declared in this scope
   return (__m128i) __builtin_ia32_phaddd128
   ((__v4si)__X, (__v4si)__Y);
                                                                      ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m128i _mm_hadds_epi16(__m128i,
__m128i)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:54:71:
error: '__builtin_ia32_phaddsw128' was not
declared in this scope
   return (__m128i) __builtin_ia32_phaddsw128
   ((__v8hi)__X, (__v8hi)__Y);
                                                                       ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m64 _mm_hadd_pi16(__m64,
__m64)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:60:65:
error: '__builtin_ia32_phaddw' was not declared
in this scope
   return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_phaddw
   ((__v4hi)__X, (__v4hi)__Y);
                                                                 ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m64 _mm_hadd_pi32(__m64,
__m64)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:66:65:
error: '__builtin_ia32_phaddd' was not declared
in this scope
   return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_phaddd
   ((__v2si)__X, (__v2si)__Y);
                                                                 ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m64 _mm_hadds_pi16(__m64,
__m64)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:72:66:
error: '__builtin_ia32_phaddsw' was not
declared in this scope
   return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_phaddsw
   ((__v4hi)__X, (__v4hi)__Y);
                                                                  ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m128i _mm_hsub_epi16(__m128i,
__m128i)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:78:70:
error: '__builtin_ia32_phsubw128' was not
declared in this scope
   return (__m128i) __builtin_ia32_phsubw128
   ((__v8hi)__X, (__v8hi)__Y);
                                                                      ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m128i _mm_hsub_epi32(__m128i,
__m128i)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:84:70:
error: '__builtin_ia32_phsubd128' was not
declared in this scope
   return (__m128i) __builtin_ia32_phsubd128
   ((__v4si)__X, (__v4si)__Y);
                                                                      ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m128i _mm_hsubs_epi16(__m128i,
__m128i)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:90:71:
error: '__builtin_ia32_phsubsw128' was not
declared in this scope
   return (__m128i) __builtin_ia32_phsubsw128
   ((__v8hi)__X, (__v8hi)__Y);
                                                                       ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m64 _mm_hsub_pi16(__m64,
__m64)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:96:65:
error: '__builtin_ia32_phsubw' was not declared
in this scope
   return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_phsubw
   ((__v4hi)__X, (__v4hi)__Y);
                                                                 ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m64 _mm_hsub_pi32(__m64,
__m64)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:102:65:
error: '__builtin_ia32_phsubd' was not declared
in this scope
   return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_phsubd
   ((__v2si)__X, (__v2si)__Y);
                                                                 ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m64 _mm_hsubs_pi16(__m64,
__m64)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:108:66:
error: '__builtin_ia32_phsubsw' was not
declared in this scope
   return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_phsubsw
   ((__v4hi)__X, (__v4hi)__Y);
                                                                  ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m128i _mm_maddubs_epi16(__m128i,
__m128i)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:114:75:
error: '__builtin_ia32_pmaddubsw128' was not
declared in this scope
   return (__m128i) __builtin_ia32_pmaddubsw128
   ((__v16qi)__X, (__v16qi)__Y);
                                                                           ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m64 _mm_maddubs_pi16(__m64,
__m64)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:120:68:
error: '__builtin_ia32_pmaddubsw' was not
declared in this scope
   return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_pmaddubsw
   ((__v8qi)__X, (__v8qi)__Y);
                                                                    ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m128i _mm_mulhrs_epi16(__m128i,
__m128i)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:126:72:
error: '__builtin_ia32_pmulhrsw128' was not
declared in this scope
   return (__m128i) __builtin_ia32_pmulhrsw128
   ((__v8hi)__X, (__v8hi)__Y);
                                                                        ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m64 _mm_mulhrs_pi16(__m64,
__m64)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:132:67:
error: '__builtin_ia32_pmulhrsw' was not
declared in this scope
   return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_pmulhrsw
   ((__v4hi)__X, (__v4hi)__Y);
                                                                   ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m128i _mm_shuffle_epi8(__m128i,
__m128i)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:138:72:
error: '__builtin_ia32_pshufb128' was not
declared in this scope
   return (__m128i) __builtin_ia32_pshufb128
   ((__v16qi)__X, (__v16qi)__Y);
                                                                        ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m64 _mm_shuffle_pi8(__m64,
__m64)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:144:65:
error: '__builtin_ia32_pshufb' was not declared
in this scope
   return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_pshufb
   ((__v8qi)__X, (__v8qi)__Y);
                                                                 ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m128i _mm_sign_epi8(__m128i,
__m128i)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:150:72:
error: '__builtin_ia32_psignb128' was not
declared in this scope
   return (__m128i) __builtin_ia32_psignb128
   ((__v16qi)__X, (__v16qi)__Y);
                                                                        ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m128i _mm_sign_epi16(__m128i,
__m128i)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:156:70:
error: '__builtin_ia32_psignw128' was not
declared in this scope
   return (__m128i) __builtin_ia32_psignw128
   ((__v8hi)__X, (__v8hi)__Y);
                                                                      ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m128i _mm_sign_epi32(__m128i,
__m128i)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:162:70:
error: '__builtin_ia32_psignd128' was not
declared in this scope
   return (__m128i) __builtin_ia32_psignd128
   ((__v4si)__X, (__v4si)__Y);
                                                                      ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m64 _mm_sign_pi8(__m64, __m64)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:168:65:
error: '__builtin_ia32_psignb' was not declared
in this scope
   return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_psignb
   ((__v8qi)__X, (__v8qi)__Y);
                                                                 ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m64 _mm_sign_pi16(__m64,
__m64)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:174:65:
error: '__builtin_ia32_psignw' was not declared
in this scope
   return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_psignw
   ((__v4hi)__X, (__v4hi)__Y);
                                                                 ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m64 _mm_sign_pi32(__m64,
__m64)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:180:65:
error: '__builtin_ia32_psignd' was not declared
in this scope
   return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_psignd
   ((__v2si)__X, (__v2si)__Y);
                                                                 ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m128i _mm_alignr_epi8(__m128i,
__m128i, int)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:188:32:
error: '__builtin_ia32_palignr128' was not
declared in this scope
            (__v2di)__Y, __N * 8);
                                ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m64 _mm_alignr_pi8(__m64, __m64,
int)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:195:27:
error: '__builtin_ia32_palignr' was not
declared in this scope
       (__v1di)__Y, __N * 8);
                           ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m128i _mm_abs_epi8(__m128i)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:211:57:
error: '__builtin_ia32_pabsb128' was not
declared in this scope
   return (__m128i) __builtin_ia32_pabsb128
   ((__v16qi)__X);
                                                         ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m128i _mm_abs_epi16(__m128i)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:217:56:
error: '__builtin_ia32_pabsw128' was not
declared in this scope
   return (__m128i) __builtin_ia32_pabsw128
   ((__v8hi)__X);
                                                        ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m128i _mm_abs_epi32(__m128i)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:223:56:
error: '__builtin_ia32_pabsd128' was not
declared in this scope
   return (__m128i) __builtin_ia32_pabsd128
   ((__v4si)__X);
                                                        ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m64 _mm_abs_pi8(__m64)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:229:51:
error: '__builtin_ia32_pabsb' was not declared
in this scope
   return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_pabsb
   ((__v8qi)__X);
                                                   ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m64 _mm_abs_pi16(__m64)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:235:51:
error: '__builtin_ia32_pabsw' was not declared
in this scope
   return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_pabsw
   ((__v4hi)__X);
                                                   ^
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:
In function '__m64 _mm_abs_pi32(__m64)':
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2019a/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/include/tmmintrin.h:241:51:
error: '__builtin_ia32_pabsd' was not declared
in this scope
   return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_pabsd
   ((__v2si)__X);
                                                   ^


Error in vl_compilenn>mex_compile (line 583)
mex(args{:}) ;

Error in vl_compilenn (line 492)
    mex_compile(opts, srcs{i}, objfile, flags)
    ;

Error in aver (line 77)
vl_compilenn()
```

Comment: This is very confusing. Are you using Visual Studio or are you using MinGW? Did you configure a 64-bit compiler? I see a lot of “32” in the error messages.

Comment: i install MinGW , bacause matlab told me that, but then, when i run vl_compilenn, it send a message saying that it needs cl.exe, for that reason i install microsft visual studio, and put that file path in my variable environment.
i tried uninstalling MinGW but then matalb say it need it

Comment: MATLAB doesn’t need MinGW. Only if you configure MEX to use it. You can also configure MEX to use MSVC. You need to configure both the C++ and the C compiler for MEX, and they need to be the same. It doesn’t matter what you have installed, no need to uninstall anything, just make sure you configure MEX correctly to use the same compiler for both C and C++.

Comment: Then follow the instructions: https://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/install/ They recommend MSVC there for Windows.  Where it says “`mex -setup mex -setup C++`” I think they missed a newline. Should be `mex -setup` and then `mex -setup C++`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, yes man you were correct, i finally solve the problem.
also i realize i had installed visual studio 2019, and mex couldnt find this compiler, so i installed visual studio 2017 community edition, uninstalled minGW64 beacouse as you say matlab doesnt need it.
and finally problem solved